# Passing around event object without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Apologies for the basic question. It's hard to find information about JS event handling without finding an explanation that includes jQuery, and I'm trying to manipulate the DOM with pure Javascript.  It's been helping me better understand how the browser works.

I'm trying to call a function to add an additional class to elements with the same class.

Can someone explain the correct syntax here?

Is it necessary to reference the ID?

I've tried a number of approaches.  Thanks so much.

```js
function animateSquare(e) {
  var id = e.target.id
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.className = el.className + "newClass";
};



window.onload = function() {
  var anim = document.getElementsByClassName("squareThing");
  for (var i = 0; i < anim.length; i++) {
    anim[i].click(function(e) {
      animateSquare(e);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="squarething" id="one"></div>
<div class="squarething" id="two"></div>
```

Comment: `.click()` is a jQuery method.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('squareThing')` does not match your `class="squarething"`

Comment: Have you looked at the mozilla documentation, which is really just general web documentation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Javascript method to add event bindings, analogous to `.on()` in jQuery, is `addEventListener`.

And when you add a class to `el.className`, you need to include a space before it, to separate it from the existing classes.

You don't need to use `getElementById(id)`, since `e.target` is the element itself -- you're getting the element, getting its ID, and then looking up the element again by ID, which is redundant.

```js
function animateSquare(e) {
  var el = e.target;
  el.className = el.className + " newClass";
};

window.onload = function() {
  var anim = document.getElementsByClassName("squarething");
  for (var i = 0; i < anim.length; i++) {
    anim[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      animateSquare(e);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.squarething {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 2px;
}
.newClass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="squarething" id="one"></div>
<div class="squarething" id="two"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough. Try it:

```js
function animateSquare() {
  this.className += " newClass";
}

window.onload = function() {
  var anim = document.getElementsByClassName("squarething");
  for (var i = 0; i < anim.length; i++) {
    anim[i].onclick = animateSquare;
  }
}
```

```css
.squarething {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .5em;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}
.squarething.newClass {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="squarething" id="one"></div>
<div class="squarething" id="two"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.click(handler)` is a jQuery method - you want the `.onclick` or `addEventListener` methods:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var anim = document.getElementsByClassName("squarething");
    for (var i = 0; i < anim.length; i++) {
        anim[i].onclick = animateSquare;
    }
}
```

You can also use `this` inside your handler function:

```
function animateSquare(e) {
    this.className = el.className + "newClass";
};
```